Reactjs: Firebase push notifications are not being received in the app
I am working on a react app which is written with typescript, and I should add the push notification ability to it using firebase ^10.11.0.
the problem is that foreground notifications are not being received at all, and background notifications are just being receive by chrome and when chrome is closed, no notification is appearing. seems like i cannot receive notification inside the application at all.
also, I should mention that this app already has service worker for PWA, and i am not sure if they are conflicting or not.
your help is very much appreciated.
for background notifications, I added firebase-messaging-sw.ts file in the public folder with below config:
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getMessaging, onBackgroundMessage } from 'firebase/messaging/sw'

const firebaseConfig = {
    // some firebase configs
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const messaging = getMessaging(app)

onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
  console.log('Received background message:', payload)

  // Customize how you want to handle the background message here
  const notificationTitle = 'hello there!'
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.messageId,
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png',
  }

  registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions)
})

and I added the registeration in the index.tsx file like this:
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
      .then((registration) => {
        console.log('Firebase Messaging Service Worker registered:', registration);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Firebase Messaging Service Worker registration failed:', error);
      });
  });
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement)
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ToastContainer />
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
)

for foreground notifications, I created a file named firebaseInit.ts inside the src folder as below:
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getMessaging, onMessage } from 'firebase/messaging'

const firebaseConfig = {
     // some firebase configs
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const messaging = getMessaging(app)

export const requestPermission = () => {
  Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
    if (permission === 'granted') {
      console.log('Notification permission granted')
    }
  })
}
requestPermission()

export const onMessageListener = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
      resolve(payload)
    })
  })
}

export default messaging

and i added this block of code into my App.tsx file:

  useEffect(() => {
    getToken(messaging, {vapidKey:'a-private-key',})
      .then((currentToken) => {
        if (currentToken) {
          console.log('your token is: ', currentToken)
        } else {
          // Costumized permission request UI
          console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.')
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token in app.tsx. ', err)
      })
  }, [])

I am not sure if i even receive notifications at all. only a notification from chrome that says this site is updated in the background
